# JpaRepository with custom Query and Composite Primary Key: error unknown column

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a SQL Server entity with a Composite Primary Key.

That is the Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plz", schema = "dbo")
@IdClass(plzId.class)
public class Plz {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "plz", columnDefinition = "NCHAR(5)")
  private String plz;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ort", columnDefinition = "NCHAR(30)")
  private String ort;

  @Column(name = "gueltigbis")
  private Date gueltigBis;

  @Column(name = "gueltigvon")
  private Date gueltigVon;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "value", columnDefinition = "NCHAR(5)")
  private String value;
}
```

and this is ID Class:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class plzId implements Serializable {

  private String plz;
  private String ort;
  private String value;
}
```

That is the JpaRepository

```
public interface PlzRepository extends JpaRepository<Plz, PlzId> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT value, ort FROM dbo.plz WHERE plz = :plz AND gueltigvon <= :bezugsdatum AND gueltigbis >= :bezugsdatum",
    nativeQuery = true
  )
  List<Plz> findByPlzDatum(@Param("plz") String plz, @Param("bezugsdatum") Date bezugsdatum);
}
```

But when this Query is executed I get an error:
Invalid Column name: plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution :-)
The select wasn't returing the full key / object. Validation on the object failed and there was not suitable constructor present.